# Different types of pressure and their sources

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics, gas, bernoulli-equation

I’m an engineering student. So far, I’ve learned about 3 types of pressure:

1. Static fluid pressure ($P=\frac{F}{A}$). This wouldn't exist without gravity. I’ve solved problems related to the force exerted on inclined surface by fluids. This concept is similar to stress in solid mechanics.
2. Static pressure of flowing fluids. According to Bernoulli’s law: $\frac{p_0}{\rho g} + z + \frac{v^2}{2g}$ is constant and the first term is called the static head. This is the pressure measured with gauges in pipes. Unlike the previous one, in steady state, reducing the cross-sectional area of pipe increases velocity and thus decreases the pressure. Reducing the velocity increases the pressure.
3. Gas pressure due to molecular motion in a cylinder and it’s exerted momentum on the cylinder’s surface. This is governed by Brownian motion and equation of state.

My questions are:

1. Since we call them "pressure", are they all the same? Is there any general law that governs all of them or are their effect/source the same?
2. What is the source of pressure in the 2nd case?

I would be glad if anyone could provide me references that treat this topic rigorously or anything that will help me to get rid of my confusion. I'm familiar with undergraduate mathematics.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We sense (measure) pressure as a force on a unit area. Consider standing at a measurement point on a given area. The two levels to consider the force we would feel are the molecular and the bulk.

At the molecular level in a fluid (gas or liquid), force arises due to a change in the momentum of a particle as it collides with the measurement point and changes direction. This is your #3. We derive the ideal gas equation of state for pressure from kinetic theory, where particles with no size and no attractive or repulsive interactions traveling at a unit average kinetic energy collide elastically with a wall of a given area. We can derive the van der Waals equation of state for pressure when we include attractive interactions between particles and give the particles a defined size. Other equations of state for pressure apply other assumptions or take an entirely empirical approach.

At the bulk level, force arises from two considerations. First, in a gravitational field, the bulk mass experiences an acceleration in the direction of the gravitational field. This is the gravitational pressure in your #1 and is modeled using barometric equations such as $\Delta p = \rho\ g\ \Delta h$. Secondly, when a bulk unit or packet of fluid is traveling cooperatively and impacts a unit area, the packet imparts a force as it changes direction at impact. This is the bulk equivalent of the molecular level force and is your #2. It is modeled by such equations as Bernoulli's equation (which has its own set of assumptions about how pressure is transmitted through the bulk fluid). The packet is not the entire fluid. It is simply a micro-region within the entire flow. The transition between molecular flow and turbulent flow can be considered as an example of when we can or cannot break the cooperative behavior of packets within a fluid and revert to the molecular behavior of particles within the packets. Viscosity measures the ability of particles to transmit shear forces between themselves. Viscosity does not exists in ideal gases, and it otherwise plays a role in defining the magnitude of cooperative behavior, hence the transition between laminar and turbulent flow.

In summary, the fact that we can model any of the given types of pressure by a certain equation (ideal gas law, barometric equation, or Bernoulli's equation) is not to be inverted and used as a way to explain the source of the given type of pressure. The fundamental source of what we define as pressure, whether at the molecular or bulk level, is a force that is being impacted on a defined unit of area.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't understand what you mean by "bulk fluid imparts a force as it changes direction at impact". Let's say I have a smooth pipe without any bends, how would there be any change of direction? Viscosity would only cause shear stresses in that case, and no normal forces would exist.

Comment: A bulk unit or packet within the fluid is not the entire fluid. Your note about viscosity translates to a realization that a fluid packet is an entity where the shear on individual molecules is transmitted effectively to neighboring fluid molecules, so that they move as a unit or packet.

Comment: Could you suggest me any book or resource for learning these concepts properly? I don't remember learning anything like this in fluid mechanics course. And thank you for your elaborate explanation.

Comment: Thank you. Search for reports on the kinetic theory of (ideal) gases for #3. This is typically covered in a first year college physics course as well as in a physical chemistry course. Search for reports on the molecular nature of liquid flow for #1 and #2. This is typically covered in advanced fluid courses, perhaps even specialized more at chemical engineers rather than other engineers (i.e. mechanical).

Answer (score 1):

Good morning. Pressure is understood as a concept in physics that represents force per unit area. In this way, it can relate substantially different concepts that have in common the existence of something that produces a force, and this force is not applied at a point, but over an area.

For example, gravity pushes air constituents "down," exerting a force on any object you consider. However, it doesn't have to be a "mechanical" force; there's also electromagnetic pressure: an electromagnetic field exerts a force on a conductor, resulting in pressure on it. Even more extreme is its application in cosmology, with pressure created by dark energy.

What I mean to convey is that pressure ties all these concepts together by the fact that they all present a distributed force that is crucial for describing a certain phenomenon. I hope I have helped!

Comment: I suspect you mean that gravity pulls, not pushes.

Answer (score -1):

Static pressure certainly can exist without gravity.  The three types of static pressure you have described are all the same. In addition, you don't need to have a solid surface for pressure to exist; static pressure is also the force per unit area exerted by a parcel of fluid on its adjacent neighboring parcels.

For an flowing inviscid fluid and for viscous fluids (both gas and liquid) in static equilibrium, the state of stress is isotropic, meaning that the compressive stress by fluid parcels on their neighbors is independent of the geometric orientation of the internal surface between the parcel and its neighbors.

However, for a deforming viscous fluid, the state of stress is not isotropic; in this case, the pressure is defined as the isotropic part of the stress tensor (the average of the three principal stresses).  In this case, the compressive stress on an internal surface of specified orientation depends on the surface orientation.